# IIS 7 leave connection after 20 sec

Tags: iis-7, webserver, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a song download portal, which is run under IIS7 web server configure with PHP v 5.4.24.Windows version 2012. When we goes to download a song file(mp3) like 4-6 mb then connection release after 20 sec and start downloading again after some time and then again release connection after 20 sec. But small file like 1 mb download properly. To resolve the issue, i have done below changes into php.ini & IIS configuration.But problem still exists :

```
1. memory_limit = 512M [increase memory limit in php.ini].
2.default_socket_timeout = 600 [increase default socket time out value php.ini]
3.Set Idle Time-out=0 into IIS default application pool.
```

please suggest to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

i have resolve the issue. Just need to unmarked the "Enable HTTP keep Alive" option in IIS.Go to IIS->HTTP Response Headers->Set Common Headers-> Enable HTTP keep Alive Section.(Unmarked the option)
[image]